# Create a set of non repeating letters in a word using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have to create a set that includes all the letters which do not repeat in a word.

example words `'balloon', 'banana'` result: `{'b','a,','n'}, {'b'}`

I actually can't figure out how to approach this, but I have tried something that's totally useless.

```
word1, word2 = {"balloon"},{"banana"}

set_word1 = set("balloon",)
set_word2 = set("banana")

print(set_word1.difference(word1))
```

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: XOR may help, but if the letters are repeated odd number of times, then it would show up :(

Comment: Try posting on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/? Sounds like something someone there might enjoy trying to solve.

Comment: Try looking at collections.Counter.  For example `collections.Counter("balloon")` will return a dictionary giving you the number of times each letter appears.  You then need to create a set out of those keys whose value is 1.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> w1="balloon"
>>> w2="banana"
>>> 
>>> def f(w):
...     return set({k for k, v in Counter(w).items() if v == 1})
... 
>>> 
>>> f(w1)
{'b', 'a', 'n'}
>>> f(w2)
{'b'}
>>>
```

set does not allow repeated elements, so if you have them it's not a set

Comment: Why are you creating a dictionary, and then throwing away the values?  Just go with: `{k for k, v in Counter(w).items() if v == 1}`

Comment: To be honest, this is not the solution I was expecting (I guess the edits I made to the question can be viewed). I already had this solution in mind but since I couldn't find any other way to do it using just the set functions, I decided to edit my question and accept this answer so that someone else could benefit from it. But I got a downvoted for it strange people out there. I don't know if they expecting me to delete the question or what.